# Bake Texture from procedural Shader to multiple Objects from Array

Tags: modifiers, texture-baking

Here's my problem (2nd attempt at explaining it btw :D)

I got a wooden panel thingy. I selected two array modifiers (x and y axis). Those are not applied yet.
I did build a shader (see below), and did adjust it, so that it makes for a reasonable wood texture. I.e.: I did tweak the parameters to achieve just the kind of texture I want across the whole array. The Shader is using procedural Textures and Object Mapping.

The Problem:
I need to apply the Array modifier to be able to modify individual objects.
When I apply the Array modifier though, the whole texture is messed up (scale and distribution among different objects)

The kind of Solution I hope for: Any way to bake the whole thing "as is": I want just the stuff I got on my screen in preview to be applied as image textures to the individual objects after applying the array modifier.

Any directions on how to solve this? Thanks!

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the Shader and the multiple wooden panels still with an unapplied array modifier.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello :). Please consider adding some images to your post, so it's easier to imagine your situation. You can also [share your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/),

Comment: Sounds like a texture coordinate issue but I concur with @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ, adding a .blend file or screenshot of the shadine nodes would greatly help...

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ here's a screenshot of what I did. Sorry for the somewhat complicated description of my problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the Array modifier needs to be applied before any texture baking.
Or it will only bake the original tile - which is not what you want.

**Another solution:**
Use *Object or UV coordinates* for *both* your textures

- the Noise Texture uses *Generated* coordinates, when it's not
  connected to anything
- but *Generated* coordinates change when you apply the Array modifier
- use *Object* coordinates instead, for *both* textures, and they will stay the same

[image]

Comment: This would be the other way around though: I do want the objects to have different textures. But as soon as I apply the array modifier, even with Object Coordinates, they all look the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired outcome. Would you mind rephrasing your original question so it's more clear? :).

Comment: Alright, I just did in the opening post. Tried to rephrase it in a more comprehensible way. :D